# Unable to render HTML template in python using swagger 2.0

Tags: python, html, flask, swagger-2.0, connexion

**Aim:**

To test all HTTP request using swagger, python, mongoDB. I'm trying to hit python function(contains 'home.html') using URL(defined in swagger) but getting raw HTML in response.
Plan is to hit it by GET request then after using HTML form will test other HTTP requests.

I have tried using flask '@app.route('/home')', it is working but it's not that I want to use.

**swagger.yml**----

```
paths:
  /app/{home}:
    get:
      summary: "fetching data from mongoDB"
      description: "description GET"
      operationId: "_read_app"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      - "application/text"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/html"
      parameters:
      - name: "home"
        in: "path"
        description: "Updated name of the person"
        required: True
        type: "string"
```

**test.py**----

```
""def _read_app(home):
    return render_template('home.html', home=home)"""
```

**html response**----

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <title> Homepage </title>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n\n<h1>Extended \"Base Template\" from base</h1>\n\n\n\n\n\n<h2>Inherited content from base to here !</h2>\n\n\n\n<h1>Welcome ,home page!</h1>\n<!--<h2>This is .</h2>-->\n\n\n<h2>This is a else block</h2>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<img src=\"/static/images/panda.jpg\">\n<h1>included from \"include.html\" to here</h1>\n<h2>name is: </h2>\n\n\n\n</body>\n\n</html>"
```

Comment: did you solve this?